# SELECT * FROM Table is not retreiving rows in inserted order

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 100k rows, `ID` is generated for each row.
When I do `Select *` from the Table, it is not retrieving rows in the inserted order.

Result set is shuffled in order of ID.

Is an `ORDER BY` necessary? Why it is not retrieving in inserted order.

Comment: You probably mean to say rows and not columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `ORDER BY` is necessary  to get the results of a select statement in a specific order. This is because tables in a relational database are unordered sets by nature.
No relational database can guarantee the order of the records returned from a select statement without an `order by` clause.
Though you might get the same order of rows many times running the same select without order by, it's not guaranteed to return every time in that specific order.

From Wikipedia's page on [relational databases:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Relations_or_tables) (emphasis mine)

> A relation is defined as a set of tuples that have the same attributes. A tuple usually represents an object and information about that object. Objects are typically physical objects or concepts. A relation is usually described as a table, which is organized into rows and columns. All the data referenced by an attribute are in the same domain and conform to the same constraints.
>
> The relational model specifies that the tuples of a relation **have no specific order and that the tuples, in turn, impose no order on the attributes.** Applications access data by specifying queries, which use operations such as select to identify tuples, project to identify attributes, and join to combine relations. Relations can be modified using the insert, delete, and update operators. New tuples can supply explicit values or be derived from a query. Similarly, queries identify tuples for updating or deleting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the only thing that *guarantees* the order in which results will be returned by a query is an `ORDER BY` clause applied at the outermost level on that query.

Anything else you may observe, that may have led you to believe that a particular order will be preferred, is *coincidence*.

If insertion order is important to you, I'd also suggest that you explicitly store that in a `datetime2` column - because I'd also generally suggest that you not place any meaning on the *numeric* value of an `IDENTITY` column - treat that as an opaque blob that just *happens* to fit in a numeric column and you'll avoid a lot of other issues later (see the ~half billion questions on this site relating to why `IDENTITY` columns contain gaps or jump by 1000 to see why)